# How to kill/start SurfaceFlinger service in Android(ADB Shell, Source)?

Tags: android, service, surfaceflinger

Android Developers!!
I have a question for SurfaceFlinger.
I'm an android TV developer. 
I'd like to start TV app without Launcher.
But the problem is that Launcher is GMS. So I can't modify this.
I can't change this scenario to excute Launcher to TV app.
So I have a trick. 
I think that disable surfaceFlinger Service firstly, because Launcher is not shown to the user.
After that, TV app is launched, enable surfaceFlinger Service.
But I don't know it is possible to control surfaceFlinger Service.
Can you give me advise? thx!

Comment: You don't want to kill SurfaceFlinger. For one thing, killing SurfaceFlinger will cause the app framework to restart. If you're just trying to blank the screen, a privileged app can ask SurfaceFlinger to put a black surface on top of everything else. Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: What I want to do is, App(TV) starts first except Launcher, But Launcher source can't be changed because it'is GMS(Google Provider app). I want to do is after booting, the first screen user seeing is app(TV), and then pressing Home button, user is possible to see the Launcher. So after booting, launcher is not shown to the user even if Launcher is executed. Can you give me some idea or tips?